# Association block is called only once

Tags: ruby, sequel

I am using Sequel and I have model defined like this:

```
class A < Sequel::Model
  one_to_one :lang, class: ALang, key: :a_id,
             graph_join_type: :inner do |ds|
               ds.where(ALang__lang: I18n.locale.to_s)
             end
  delegate :title, :titleSanitized, :description, to: :lang
  # ...
end


I18n.lang = :de
A.eager(:lang).all 
# block is called ("ds.where(ALang__lang: I18n.locale.to_s)" code)
# database was queried (I can see the query in logs) 
I18n.lang = :en
A.eager(:lang).all 
# block is not called
# database was queried (I can see the query in logs)
```

Is it bug or feature? Or am I doing something wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the block is eagerly evaluated and the resulting dataset is cached. To delay the evaluation of the current locale, you need to use a delayed evaluation:

```
one_to_one :lang, class: ALang, key: :a_id,
         graph_join_type: :inner do |ds|
           ds.where(ALang__lang: Sequel.delay{I18n.locale.to_s})
         end
```

I've updated Sequel's documentation to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming when you're saying "block" you're meaning the body of the `A` `class` or something within said body, that makes perfect sense. Classes are only loaded once (typically, unless monkey patching, but even then "loading" is a debatable term).

The body of `A`, in this case, sets up the *declarative* logic of of the queries you are performing. If you're talking abut the block passed to `one_to_one` it's likely `Sequel::Model` is calculating its result and caching it when the class is being loaded.

Am I missing the question here?

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear, I ment the block which contains `ds.where(ALang__lang: I18n.locale.to_s)` code.

Comment: Gotcha, it appears from @spickermann's answer that my hunch was correct.

Comment: See end "If you're talking abut the block passed to one_to_one it's likely Sequel::Model is calculating its result and caching it when the class is being loaded."

Comment: Ok, this is understandable. But therefore I can't see the point to use block definition in association if it is not able to reflect dynamic state. Do you understand me? I believe I am doing something wrong, but I am not able to figure out what :(.

Answer (score 0):

That is a feature:

The block is only evaluated one, when the class is loaded. This is the reason why you use lambdas in ActiveRecord to define variable parts in scopes or associations. I don't know if Sequel also supports lambdas in query or association definitions.

The database is not called twice, because associations are cached after being retrieved. See [Caching in the docs for `Sequel::Model`](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/association_basics_rdoc.html#label-Caching)

Comment: Ok, but why is the database queried in both calls? Please see the edited question. Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you see the query in the Rails log or in your database's log? The Rails log only tells you that Rails requested that data, but not if the caching layer was able to deliver it. In the result for a query is available in the caching layer, you would see the query in the Rails log, but not in your database's log, since it actually does not kit the database twice.

Comment: The problem was not in caching data but caching dataset for association. All is solved now. Thank you for your time.